# DotNetOpenAuth getting Access Token Google Consumer

Tags: oauth, dotnetopenauth

I modified google consumer to use in my application scenario.

My scenario is to authenticate user on our client's website and then log them into our system. I am able to do the following:

1) Get Request Token
2) Redirect them to the client's site. User enters username and password and they come back to our URL.

After this step I cannot get the access token.

var accessTokenResponse = google.ProcessUserAuthorization(); is always null.

Our client told me that when they return back to us they don't include the verifier and signed request token. I am not sure if that is the reason why I can't get this working.

Can someone please help? I am new to this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing authentication then your use of OAuth is probably inappropriate.  You should be using OpenID of you're authenticating via Google.

As long as you're using OAuth, yes, the verifier string is mandatory.

Comment: I actually was able to get it working by creating my own HttpRequestInfo object. Can you please guide me why I should use openID? The user gets on our site, we redirect them to our clients website for authentication. Its exactly like the example for getting contacts in google. thnaks

Comment: I don't understand how redirecting a user to a client web site for authentication is exactly like a sample that doesn't authenticate a user, but instead obtains some resource (contacts) from Google.  Without knowing more about your scenario, I can only speak generally: OpenID is for authentication; OAuth is for authorization.  Misusing security protocols often defeats the security model they provide and leaves you open for attacks.